# jquery/javascript loading confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery and some ordinary javascript on my site and I've been told that I'd be better off loading all the javascript in a minimized form at the closing body tag of my pages rather than in the header as they are now.

I've also been told that I should clump all my JS together into one file to keep the number of requests down, although I've also been told there's some of my javascript which won't be able to be included in this mega file because it's needed by FB (for example).

So now I'm totally confused. For a start, 
1) I use jquery and the jquery.ui, can these be lumped into the mega file and loaded at the end?

2) Can I just stick everything which currently appears in my page source surrounded by script tags into this file?

3) What must I leave out?

It's all a bit over-whelming when you're a learner

the site is at http://www.traditionalirishgifts.com/ as you can see I load:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

as well as a heap of other javascripts

Comment: There really isn't a "best" way to do it, it all depends on your situation, target audience, application structure, application type, what scripts are needed, etc.. To begin with, just keep it simple. If you have problems later with page load taking too long, look into reducing the amount of code you are loading in and/or reducing the number of http requests. stylesheets in the head, scripts before closing body tag.

Comment: yeah, but can I load all the jquery stuff as just one file?

Comment: Sure you can (just make sure you keep the licensing in-tact). However it may be faster to just link to the CDN if the user has it cached.

Comment: Ah, OK, so I should just load those from CDN and the rest from one big mega file? What about FB stuff? And is it ok to load the jquery stuff at the bottom too?

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out, the answer depends on many variables.

Are you using any server side web framework? Any web framework worth it's money will offer you options for javascript and css concatenation. Typically these options allow you to define how exactly you want the concatenation to happen. Certain js files will change infrequently, example jquery, jquery ui. Whereas certain other files will change frequently, example your own application scripts. All these can be taken into consideration when deciding on what to concatenate.

If you could share which server side technology and what web server are you using, I can help you find specific solutions.

**With regards to your three questions,** its all about managing your dependencies. If your application scripts or "whatever currently appears in my page source surrounded by script tags" depend on jQuery or any other library, then they will need to included AFTER jquery or said library.

Dependency could also exist wrt the DOM. If your scripts output html directly using `document.write` then you will not be able to move them around easily.

I went through the html of the homepage of the site you linked to. The js code in that file can be moved to just before the end of the body, though you will need to ensure they appear in the same order. All the plugins you have included they seem to initialize themselves on `document.ready` which occurs only after all the html/js/css is parsed.

You are already referencing jquery/jqueryui from a CDN, so don't add them to the concatenated file.

I did not notice any code that you wouldn't be able to concatenate (on account of using FB). That said you could ask the person, who told you that, to explain why.

Finally, you can read more about optimizing front-end load times on [YSlow (http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) and [Google Page Speed (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro)](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro)

Personally, I would suggest you go ahead and move everything to just before the end of body. If something breaks, then ask questions on SO specific to the errors you receive.